# How do I add a certain number of spaces to the beginning of a string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm using Ruby 2.3.  How do I add a certain number of spaces to the beginning of a string?  I thought rjust was the way to do it, but these calls do nothing when I want to add 1 space of padding to the front of the string ..

```
line = "  29  25  13 M10-19 14    23:36  7:36    826 HYLLBERG MARCO      WI Kenosha"
# => "  29  25  13 M10-19 14    23:36  7:36    826 HYLLBERG MARCO      WI Kenosha" 
line.rjust(1)
# => "  29  25  13 M10-19 14    23:36  7:36    826 HYLLBERG MARCO      WI Kenosha"
```

Comment: To use [String#rjust](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-rjust), to add, say, two spaces at the beginning, write `line.rjust(line.size+2)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
line = "  29  25  13 M10-19 14    23:36  7:36    826 HYLLBERG MARCO      WI Kenosha"
#=> "  29  25  13 M10-19 14    23:36  7:36    826 HYLLBERG MARCO      WI Kenosha"
line.prepend(" ")
#=> "   29  25  13 M10-19 14    23:36  7:36    826 HYLLBERG MARCO      WI Kenosha"
line.prepend(" " * 2) # for a variable number of spaces
#=> "    29  25  13 M10-19 14    23:36  7:36    826 HYLLBERG MARCO      WI Kenosha"
```

Comment: Thanks but how would I do this with a variable number of spaces?  I put "1"  just as an example, but what if the nubmer were stored in a variable called "num_spaces"?

Comment: you can use the multiplication operator

Answer (score 2):

If you want to format that to a particular width:

```
line =  "  29  25  13 M10-19 14    23:36  7:36    826 HYLLBERG MARCO      WI Kenosha"
'%76s' % line
```

The `sprintf` [formatting directives](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-format) make it easy to organize things that way.

Comment: Hi, I don't want to format to a particular width, I want to add a certain number of spaces in front of the string.  It's not necessarily the same because I have no idea what the total length of the string should be, only the number of spaces I want to add.

Comment: Usually you add spaces to get a desired length, but if that's not the case then go with @baseballlover723's solution.